# how to - Dynamic textBox push down anther textBox

Tags: flash, textbox, actionscript-2, flash-cs6

I'm using CS6 and AS2 with a 2 multi-line dynamic text boxes beneath one another. 
When I populate the top text box I would like it to automatically push down the other 
text boxes beneath it when the content flows on to extra lines.

the instance name of the upper text Box is : bisname
the instance name of the beneath text Box is : locationtxt
and both of them under a - "onEnterFrame" function

whats the code.....

please HELP !!! 
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
function myOnEnterFrameHandler(){
   locationtxt._y = bisname._y + bisname.textHeight;
}
```